# Optional argument to \item

Tags: lists, enumitem, optional-arguments

I am typesetting an ordered list where the entries may appear out of order, but should be assumed in order otherwise. I don't want to have to jump through `\setcounter` hoops to do this. That is, I want something like

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item[8] Eighth!
  \item Ninth!
  \item[4] Fourth
\end{enumerate}
```

to give the following Good output, instead of the Bad output:

[image: Good and Bad outputs, as given by MWE below]

A minimum working example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % preferably something compatible with this guy
\begin{document}

Good:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1.] First
  \item[2.] Second
  \item[8.] Eighth!
  \item[9.] Ninth!
  \item[4.] Fourth
\end{enumerate}

Bad:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item[8] Eighth!
  \item Ninth!
  \item[4] Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It should be noted that I don't want to have to specify the period afterwards, in case my list using a different numbering, e.g. Roman. Compatibility with `enumitem` is preferred, but not required.

What is the correct way of going about this?

Comment: And what should the counter return if you have a plain `\item` after the `\item[4] Fourth`? Will it be 6? 3? something else?

Comment: If you tell us what interface are you looking for it would be easier. I mean, you want that the optional argument changes only the value of the counter, and then let the label print itself (that would mean, under certain circumstances, that `\item[1]` would print `(a)`, for instance), or you want to have both options. In case it's the latter, what “interface” are you thinking of to differentiate both situations?

Comment: @jon It should return 5, just like the `\item` after `\item[8]` returns 9.

Comment: And if there are 4 `\item`s after the fourth one? Should it use `8` again?

Comment: What does 'compatible' mean? That you need to be able to use the standard `enumitem` options to further customise the output? Or that you can use the packages facilities for other environments, but not the customised one?

Comment: @cfr Sure. With optional argument, it changes the counter; without, it simply increments.

Comment: @cfr I would like `[label=(\letter*)]` to work, at least.

Comment: @algorithmshark Well that isn't even supported by `enumitem`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to abuse the optional argument to `\item`; better defining a `\nextitem` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nextitem[1]{%
  \setcounter{\@enumctr}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{\@enumctr}{-1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\nextitem{8}
\item Eighth!
\item Ninth!
\nextitem{4}
\item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}
  {\let\originalitem\item
   \RenewDocumentCommand\item{o}{\IfValueTF{#1}
     {\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\originalitem}{\originalitem}}}

\begin{document}

Good:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item[8] Eighth!
  \item Ninth!
  \item[4] Fourth
\end{enumerate}

And

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item[8] Eighth!
  \item Ninth!
  \item[4] Fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I removed some `\begingroup..\endgroup` I had originally, and I don't know why it works the same way wether I grouped or not.

This does only work with one level enumerations. You can't nest `enumerate`s.

[image]

Comment: You can always get the original behaviour with `\originalitem`.