# Redefine optional argument to item

Tags: lists, enumitem, optional-arguments

Similarly to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225429/9953), I would like the optional argument of the `\item` command to print the number of points. Since I don't want to define a new list environment or a custom `\item` command I tried the following code (inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226611/9953)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xparse}

\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\let\olditem\item%
      \RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{o}{%
      \IfValueTF{#1}{#1 points}\olditem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[1)]
  \item This is some item
  \item[10] This item is worth something
  \item Another item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However this doesn't work since it gives the result seen in the image. I'm obviously doing something (or several things wrong). Thanks in advance for the help.

BONUS: Ideally the solution should work with various enumerate levels (i.e nested environments).

[image]

Comment: You need something like `\IfValueTF{#1}{\olditem[#1 points]}\olditem`

Comment: Where and how you want the number of points to be printed?

Comment: Hi @egreg. I would like the points to be printed likes this "1. [10 points] First item"  i. e after the enumerate counter and before the item text.

Comment: @petobens And isn't it simpler to input `\item\points{10} First item` where you define `\newcommand{\points}[1]{[#1 points]}`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you provide a complete answer? Your suggestions doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: @egreg it is simpler but since I never use the optional argument to the `\item` command I thought that maybe I could redefine it and finally use it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You won't finally be using it. You'll be using a different command which it would be better to treat to a name of its own. You can easily make this work for the simple case, but it breaks nested lists immediately because, as defined, you end up a definition in terms of itself. (Because at the first sub-list, `\olditem` is defined to the current, redefined `\item` and then that is redefined in terms of `\olditem` which is defined in terms of.... Of course, it can be done. But it cannot possibly be worth doing. It will also make your code less readable and less flexible.

Comment: You need to explain *how* it should work still. Try removing your redefinition and just write `\item[10 points]`. You will see output different than what you are probably hoping for.  If that is true, you'll need to think pretty carefully about many list-related spacing issues before coming up with a solution that will work correctly in nested lists.  I also have to concur that a separate macro definition is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the advantage of this method over a simpler input such as

```
\item\points{10}
```

but here it is. It's a bad idea to modify the stock enumerate environment, even if the document only uses it for the purpose of writing assignment texts, so I define a new environment based on `enumitem` features, so you can further customize it with an optional argument. Also it's better to define outside the environment the macro that replaces `\item`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\latexitem\item
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointitem}{o}{%
  \latexitem
  \IfValueT{#1}{\everypar=\expandafter{\the\everypar\formatpoints{#1}}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatpoints}{m}{[#1 points] }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{assignments}{O{}}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),ref=\arabic*,#1]\let\item\pointitem}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{assignments}

\item This is some item

\item[10] This item is worth something

\item Another item

\end{assignments}

\end{document}
```

Using `\everypar` is for allowing usage of `\label` in the same way it can be used with the standard `\item`.

[image]